# Make a numpy array selecting only certain rows and certain columns from another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have created a very large NumPy array of size 500 x 10000, called `first_array`, to solve a partial differential equation using the Crank Nicolson method. This method needs to create and use all the data stored in the array, but I only need a small part of it. For example, 50 rows and 50 columns would be enough.

How could I create a smaller array, `second_array`, from `first_array` by selecting only those rows and columns that are multiples of a certain number? Is there any built-in NumPy method for this task?

For example, if `first_array` is

```py
array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
       [21, 22, 23, 24],
       [31, 32, 33, 34],
       [14, 42, 43, 44]])
```

then I would like `second_array` to be an array formed with the 1st and 3d rows of `first_array` and with the 2ns and 4th column of `first_array`:

```py
array([[12, 14],
       [32, 34],])
```

Comment: can you provide a **minimal** example of input output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
import numpy as np

first_array = np.random.rand(500,1000)
row_factor = 10
row_start = 1
col_factor = 10
col_start = 1
second_array = first_array[row_start:-1:row_factor,col_start:-1:col_factor]
print(second_array.shape)
```

You can make simple slicing where you skip row_factor or col_factor in both direction

Comment: It works perfectly with 2D arrays! Could it also be applied to 1D arrays? I tried `1D_array[col_start:-1:col_factor]`, but didn't work.

Comment: You cannot name a variable starting with a number. but it works `import numpy as np      
D1_array = np.random.rand(500)
      
col_factor = 10      
col_start = 1      
D2_array = D1_array[col_start:-1:col_factor]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as such:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
y = x[slice(0,-1,3), slice(0,-1,4)].copy()
```

Now you have selected every row which is a multiple of 3, and every column which is a multiple of 4. You can adjust the slice `start` and `end` points if you want to start at a specific offset.

Note: you need to use `.copy()` if you want to avoid modifying the original array `x`. Otherwise slices are just a view to the original array.